# Am I doing it correct? Why date not showing up?

Tags: reactjs

Need a field with datepicker. The calendar is showing, I can select the Date, but nothing showing up.

Wrote my code in src/components/DatePicker/index.js
and calling in src/formpage.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-date-picker';

class Calendar extends Component {
  state = {
    date: new Date(),
  }

  onChange = date => this.setState({ date })

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={this.state.date}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default DatePicker;
```

No error showing.. But the date also not showing after we select the date

Comment: are you sure you're importing from `react-datepicker`, not `react-date-picker` ?

Comment: Error in ./src/components/DatePicker/index.js
Module not found: 'react-datepicker' in

Comment: change the import to `react-date-picker` or run the command `npm i react-datepicker`

Comment: import DatePicker from './components/DatePicker';                                                         this is how I imported from src/components/Datepicker/index.js                                                              and calling src/formPage.js

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong prop in `DatePicker`.

It isn't `value` but `selected` for the date value.

```
<DatePicker
    onChange={this.onChange}
    selected={this.state.date} // selected
/>
```

You can see an example that is `selected` in the first example on the [docs](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/#installation).

Comment: when I click the text, the whole screen became blank.

Answer (score 0):

[This the image of error showing in WebInspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxR8F.png)